# Проблема с установкой MS SQL 2016

Tags: windows, sql-server, windows-server-2012

Дано: Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard x64 RU + Microsoft SQL Server 2016 RTM EE RU.
В процессе установки возникает следующая ошибка:

[image: Ошибка]

Далее видно, что не установились следующие компоненты:

[image: Ошибка установки]

Ок, смотрю как написано в лог-файл Summary но ничего, что может натолкнуть на понимание проблемы не вижу:

```
Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент, а затем запустите установку еще раз.
  Next step for DQ:              Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент, а затем запустите установку еще раз.
  Next step for FullText:        Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент, а затем запустите установку еще раз.
  Next step for AdvancedAnalytics: Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент, а затем запустите установку еще раз.
  Next step for Replication:     Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент, а затем запустите установку еще раз.

.......

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Соединение с клиентскими средствами
  Status:                        Завершено

  Feature:                       Пакет SDK клиентских средств
  Status:                        Завершено

  Feature:                       Службы ядра СУБД
  Status:                        Ошибка. Дополнительные сведения см. в журнале.
  Reason for failure:            Произошла ошибка во время процесса установки компонента.
  Next Step:                     Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент, а затем запустите установку еще раз.
  Component name:                Экземпляры служб ядра СУБД SQL Server
  Component error code:          0x851A001A
  Error description:             Ошибка при ожидании дескриптора восстановления ядра СУБД. Возможные причины см. в журнале ошибок SQL Server.

  Feature:                       Служба Data Quality Services
  Status:                        Ошибка. Дополнительные сведения см. в журнале.
  Reason for failure:            Возникла ошибка для одной из зависимостей компонента, вызвавшая сбой процесса его установки.
  Next Step:                     Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент, а затем запустите установку еще раз.
  Component name:                Экземпляры служб ядра СУБД SQL Server
  Component error code:          0x851A001A
  Error description:             Ошибка при ожидании дескриптора восстановления ядра СУБД. Возможные причины см. в журнале ошибок SQL Server.

  Feature:                       Полнотекстовый и семантический поиск
  Status:                        Ошибка. Дополнительные сведения см. в журнале.
  Reason for failure:            Возникла ошибка для одной из зависимостей компонента, вызвавшая сбой процесса его установки.
  Next Step:                     Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент, а затем запустите установку еще раз.
  Component name:                Экземпляры служб ядра СУБД SQL Server
  Component error code:          0x851A001A
  Error description:             Ошибка при ожидании дескриптора восстановления ядра СУБД. Возможные причины см. в журнале ошибок SQL Server.

  Feature:                       R Services (в базе данных)
  Status:                        Ошибка. Дополнительные сведения см. в журнале.
  Reason for failure:            Произошла ошибка во время процесса установки компонента.
  Next Step:                     Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент, а затем запустите установку еще раз.
  Component name:                R Services (в базе данных)
  Component error code:          0x80131509
  Error description:             Cannot find group with identity S-1-5-21-3440621758-1074549526-1447665842-1131.

  Component name:                Экземпляры служб ядра СУБД SQL Server
  Component error code:          0x851A001A
  Error description:             Ошибка при ожидании дескриптора восстановления ядра СУБД. Возможные причины см. в журнале ошибок SQL Server.


  Feature:                       Репликация SQL Server
  Status:                        Ошибка. Дополнительные сведения см. в журнале.
  Reason for failure:            Возникла ошибка для одной из зависимостей компонента, вызвавшая сбой процесса его установки.
  Next Step:                     Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент, а затем запустите установку еще раз.
  Component name:                Экземпляры служб ядра СУБД SQL Server
  Component error code:          0x851A001A
  Error description:             Ошибка при ожидании дескриптора восстановления ядра СУБД. Возможные причины см. в журнале ошибок SQL Server.


  Feature:                       Браузер SQL
  Status:                        Завершено

  Feature:                       Компоненты документации
  Status:                        Завершено

  Feature:                       Модуль записи SQL
  Status:                        Завершено

  Feature:                       Средства связи клиента SQL
  Status:                        Завершено

  Feature:                       Пакет SDK средств связи клиента SQL
  Status:                        Завершено

  Feature:                       Файлы поддержки программы установки
  Status:                        Завершено
```

Вопрос в том, почему не устанавливается и как сделать, чтобы установилось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже нет прав на установку. Перейдите на экран конфигурации сервера, измените имя учетной записи компонента Database Engine на **NT Authority\Network Service** и продолжите установку, ошибки не должно быть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
<sub>(источник: [alta.ru](https://www.alta.ru/images/support/mssqlserver2005/MS_SQL_2012_image007.png))</sub>

Comment: Спасибо, действительно так работает! Единственное, что учётную запись не получалось ввести руками - пришло искать через поиск. Но в итоге всё работает)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Региональные стандарты]

Есть ещё одна причина по которой SQL выдаёт такую же ошибку при установке. Если в параметрах региональных стандартов стоит галка "Использовать Юникод (UTF-8)", SQL на этапе установки будет выдавать ошибку 0x851A001A.

Собственно для решения данной проблемы эту галку нужно убрать.