# Ошибка при ожидание дескриптора ядра в СУБД. SQL Server 2022 Express

Tags: sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Такую ошибку выдает при заверешние, не понимаю, что делать. Раньше была ошибка, что не находит дискриптор ядра. Удалила все, что скачивала и решила по новой. По итогу опять ошибка с дискриптором.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Желательно добавь в вопрос лог установки, возможно это упростит поиск ответа.
Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/555044/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-ms-sql-2016