# Не удалось установить SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Пытаюсь установить SQL Server, но выдает ошибку, как на скриншоте.
Удалил с компьютера все, что связано с SQL, перезагрузился, но ошибка все-равно вознкает.
Не пойму, в чем дело.

В логах с ошибкой написано, что нужно удалить компонент, но я и так уже все удалил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте ответы отсюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/555044/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-ms-sql-2016